# requiring php config classes, but file not found

Tags: php, include, config, require

In my opinion I'm requiring all necessary files but I keep getting the error that one file is not found. All files are in the same folder.

This is my code for zConfig.php:

```
<?php
class zConfig {
    static $confArray;
    public static function read($name) {
        return self::$confArray[$name];
    }
    public static function write($name, $value) {
        self::$confArray[$name] = $value;
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my code for bd2.php:

```
require_once('zConfig.php');

/*
 * Write settings to the config
 */
zConfig::write('hostname', 'XXXX');
zConfig::write('database', 'XXXX');
zConfig::write('username', 'XXXX');
zConfig::write('password', 'XXXX');
zConfig::write('drivers', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

Finally, this is my code for a function within Product.php:

```
public function pdo_updateTip($which, $tiptext)
{
  require_once("bd2.php");
  try {
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".bd2::read('hostname').";dbname=".bd2::read('database')."", bd2::read('username'), bd2::read('password'), bd2::read('drivers'));
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tip SET tip_text = :tiptext WHERE product_id='0' AND item LIKE :which");
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':tiptext'   => $tiptext,
    ':which' => $which
  ));

echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
    return true;
}
```

The error I'm getting when I load Product.php is this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'bd2' not found in /home/xxxxx/Product.php on line 45
```

Line 45 is the line where I first refer to `bd2`, here:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".bd2::read('hostname').";dbname=".bd2::read('database')."", bd2::read('username'), bd2::read('password'), bd2::read('drivers'));
```

Comment: You are including a class in bd2.php, but actually bd2 is not a class. You should be using the classname instead -> zConfig::read('hostname');

Comment: Where is bd2 class because I can't find it? PHP won't find it too.

Comment: Dude, use autoloading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".zConfig::read('hostname').";dbname=".zConfig::read('database')."", zConfig::read('username'), zConfig::read('password'), zConfig::read('drivers'));
```

`bd2` is not a class and therefore it does not contain any static method `read`. It seems that it is just a file that sets the configuration for your database by using the `zConfig::write` method.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you the power of autoloading in PHP.

If you follow [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md), it will be quite simple.

Suppose you have a structure like this:

```
Project/
--conf/
--classes/
--index.php
```

So, you put this on `conf` directory, with a name you prefer:

```
<?php
/**
* @author Henrique Barcelos <rick.hjpbarcelos@gmail.com>
* @copiright (c) 2013, Henrique Barcelos
*/

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

setlocale(LC_ALL, array('es_ES', 'es_ES.iso-8859-1', 'es_ES.utf-8', 'spanish'));
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Madrid');

define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

set_include_path(
    implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,
        array_unique(
            array_merge(
                array(
                    APP_ROOT . 'YOUR_CLASS_DIRECTORY', 
                ),
                explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path())
            )
        )
    )
);

{
    function autoload($class) {
        $file = sprintf("%s.php", str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class));
        if (($classPath = stream_resolve_include_path($file)) != false) {
            require $classPath;
        }
    }

    spl_autoload_register('autoload', true);
}
```

In your `index.php` you just do:

```
require 'conf/NAME_OF_THE_FILE';
```

And *voilá*, you will have all of you classes loaded.
For example, your class `db2` should be put right inside your class directory.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone who ends up here looking for an answer to the "class not found" problem.  I *require* a PHP mailer script that I found somewhere on the net. My own script that does the requiring was written a long time ago and at the time it was working perfectly.

I am in the process of moving servers (with the new one using a later version of PHP). I too ran into this issue and searched high & low for a solution.  In the end the problem turned out to be a very trivial one.  It turned out that the PHP mailer script was using

<?
...
?>

and that was apparently enough to confuse my new server.  I changed the starting tag to <?php and everything was hunkry dory again.